# Excel userform label different color text

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I am creating a userform in Excel, I have a Label with a large amount of text in. I need to have certain words in Bold and in Red color and the rest in standard black.

I can change the whole text color in the properties but not just certain words.

Is this possible and if so how would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Select certain word and fill with BOLD or make it RED
Also this depends on your Excel Version, I using Excel 2013

Comment: I'm currently using excel 2007. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that it isn't possible..

You'll have to create different Labels in order to change only certain parts of your text color.